# Bootstrap col offset not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap to draw my page. I want to put the 'Title' not started with the line. But the col-md-offset-4 does not work.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">Beyond forever</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center"><em>My favorite band</em></h2>
    <div class="thumbnail text-center"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deqlvmd9w/image/upload/v1494666517/beyond_ihkzoj.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/heshijinghuang/opsv0e09/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your reply. The issue has been solved. It is because boostrap 4 using different offset style(offset-sm-2）In bootstrap 3, it's col-offset-sm-2.

Answer (score 0):

It works :) Try to resize JSFiddle result tab. It's size is just to small to be `md` size. If you want to achieve the same result on small screens, use `sm` or `xs` classes, like `col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4` or `col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4`.

Comment: please note `col-xs-offset-*` does not exist any more since Bootstrap 3.1

Answer (score 0):

`col-md-offset-4` "does not work" in your jsfiddle because the jsfiddle view area is very small, which makes `-md-` not work any more.

To make it work in jsfiddle, you need to change it to `col-sm-offset-4`, and expand the view area a bit.

BTW, If the header need to be centered via `col-*-offset-*`, I think it is better to use `col-sm-offset-2` for your case.

I've made a new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/opsv0e09/2/). Please check (need to resize the result panel and increase its width).

Answer (score 0):

you are styling medium size screen `md`, while JSfiddle html renderer falls in small size `sm`

change your `col-md-8 col-md-offset-4` to `col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4` and it will work